# How would I make it so that it would display a different message once a threshold has been passed?

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is make it so that when a number of guesses is passed it will just make it so that it will display the same message until they close and reenter the app but I can't figure out how to do this.

My current code for the game is this:

```
    String randtext ="";
      Random rand = new Random();
      int noofguess = 0;
        int n = rand.nextInt(20)+1; //generate random number
        int userguess = Integer.parseInt(etCommentInput.getText().toString());
        if (userguess < 1 || userguess > 20){
            tvCommentOuput.setText("Please enter a number between 1-20!");
        }
        else if (userguess == n){
            tvCommentOuput.setText("You Got It Right!");
        } else if (userguess > n) {
            tvCommentOuput.setText("Number too high!");
            noofguess = noofguess + 1;
        } else{
            tvCommentOuput.setText("Number too low!");
            noofguess = noofguess + 1;
        } 


        tvCommentOuput.setText("Please enter a number between 1-20!");


        randtext = Integer.toString(n);

}
}
```

What I was thinking of doing is surrounding it in an if statement so that if noofguess is less than 3 it will run the regular program but if it is above three then it will just display that they have run out of guesses but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to surround part of your code with a while loop

```
String randtext ="";
Random rand = new Random();
int noofguess = 0;
int n = rand.nextInt(20)+1; //generate random number
do{
int userguess =     Integer.parseInt(etCommentInput.getText().toString());
if (userguess < 1 || userguess > 20){
    tvCommentOuput.setText("Please enter a number between 1-20!");
}
else if (userguess == n){
    tvCommentOuput.setText("You Got It Right!");
    break;
} else if (userguess > n) {
    tvCommentOuput.setText("Number too high!");
    noofguess = noofguess + 1;
} else{
    tvCommentOuput.setText("Number too low!");
    noofguess = noofguess + 1;
} 


tvCommentOuput.setText("Please enter a number between 1-20!");


randtext = Integer.toString(n);
}
while(noofguess < 3);
// add if statement here to deal with the case where there are too many guesses
```

Comment: I tried this but when i ran it it caused the application to quit before allowing me to enter anything.

Comment: @assd Oh whoops. Noticed an issue in the logic. Fixed now.

Comment: @assd Another question:
What is etCommentInput? Also, are you sure that etCommentInput.getText().toString() is working? 
I personally would use a Scanner with System.in (Console input) to test the logic before doing more complicated stuff.
Next time, change it to a minimum working example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting. Get rid of all gui stuff unless that is the issue.